# Bar chart of a data in Python

Tags: python

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3','abc4'], 'age':[21,23,45,34],
'marks':[20, 24, 34, 18]})
 df
```

So I want to plot a bar chart with x axis being the age group.
 Say I want my  groups to be :

```
10-20, 20-30, 30-40, 40-50
```

I am new to plotting in Python Can you please help.

Comment: Given that you want age groups on the x-axis, can you clarify what you want on the y-axis? For example: average marks in the age group?

Comment: frequency of people in the age group.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `matplotlib` library for this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_histogram_06():
    data = np.random.normal(loc=30, scale=10, size=[1000, 1])
    bins = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70)
    plt.hist(data, bins=bins)
    plt.savefig('my_plot_06.png')
    plt.close()
```

[image: Histogram for age]

You can add `normed=True` in the `hist` argument list if you want to normalize the y-axis. For further options, I refer to the `matplotlib` manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3','abc4'], 'age':[21,23,45,34], 'marks':[20, 24, 34, 18]})
df['age'].hist(bins=[10,20,30,40,50])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but my data is huge so I want x axis to be groups rather than particular age also I want y axis to be the frequency of people falling in that age group.